# Applying unique constraint of date on TIMESTAMP column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, sql-timestamp

I have a postgresql table as

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name
(
    expiry_date DATE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
    CONSTRAINT user_review_uniq_key UNIQUE (expiry_date, created_at::date) -- my wrong attempt of using ::
)
```

I want to put uniue constraint on this table in such a way that expiry_date and date of created_at should be unique. Problem is created_at column is timestamp not date.

so is there any way to put unique constraint such that expire_date and created_at::date should be unique?

My attempt was to use
`CONSTRAINT user_review_uniq_key UNIQUE (expiry_date, created_at::date)` which is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need a time zone for your created date : create a unique index has follows :

```
create unique index idx_user_review_uniq_key on  table_name (expiry_date, cast(created_at as date));
```

If you need that badly to have a time zone then you need to use a little trick (https://gist.github.com/cobusc/5875282) :

```
create unique index idx_user_review_uniq_key on  table_name (expiry_date, date(created_at at TIME zone 'UTC'));
```

Comment: doesn't  works for me when i try  to create unique , just  throw error on cast `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cast"
LINE 2: ...id_desc_date UNIQUE (pwk_prp_id, pwk_description, cast(pwk_c...`  postgres 9.6